# How do you log into a website using swift NSURL?

Tags: swift, authentication, web

I am trying to use swift to log into a website.

Im relativley new to swift, but I have been taking a course on Udemy for a couple weeks now. The course explains how to grab the html from a site and display information based on the html, but it does not explain how you would take user input of say a username and password from the app and pass that to the website to log in. Once logged into the site I want to use the information the site provides to show up in my app. I dont want this app to be a web browser I just need the initial login part.

Ive been using NSURL and such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have searched and searched and I haven't been able to find anything helpful.

Comment: Which course are you taking?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way that I found that worked for me.

I had created my own Login UI to get the user to enter their details.

So to get them to login in I had a hidden UIWebView and used  webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("") for each field and submit button. Then you download the HTML again and check for a successful login, which will also get you the HTML for whatever is on that page.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("")
}
```

So for instance, to fill in stack overflow's email field

```
// Email Field   
   webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[3].value = \"youremail@domain.com\"")
```